# Theme font does not go through

Tags: emacs, themes

I created the [kooten-theme](https://github.com/kootenpv/emacs-kooten-theme), in which I'm using one of the most popular monospace fonts.

This is the line I use for it:

```
'(default ((t (:family "Consolas" :foundry "nil" :width normal :height 180 :weight normal 
 :slant normal :underline nil :overline nil :strike-through nil :box nil :inverse-video nil 
 :foreground "white" :background "#14151E" :stipple nil :inherit nil))))
```

See:

https://github.com/kootenpv/emacs-kooten-theme/blob/master/kooten-theme.el#L72

It loads perfectly fine, but it does not on a VM (neither Ubuntu nor Fedora).

So I figured, probably the font is not available. But when I <kbd>M-x customize-face RET default</kbd> and set the font to Consolas/nil (instead of the OS default), then it simply does work.

What is wrong?

Comment: I would check your init.el files on both machines and in particular the customize sections of those files. It is possible that another default font setting has been added. Also check that your theme is being installed and not merged with existing theme. Are the VMs running the same OS or something different?

Comment: @TimX They are running a different OS (I run MacOSX by default). When looking at the default font, it says "THEMED" in the customization buffer. It puts the font to, `TlwgMono`, and font `height: 181`.  But again, I can just easily switch to Consolas, so it is available... but of course I wouldn't want others to have to change it.

Comment: I have never run emacs on windows, only linux and osx. If there is nothing else in your init.el, such as something in the custom section, I wonder if there might be an environment variable which is being used by emacs to set the font and that is overriding your setting? I also vaguely remember something about windows fonts where a registry setting was overriding the default. Perhaps check to see if there is a font set int he windows registry?

Comment: @TimX Windows has not been involved in my tests.... Mac/Fedora/Ubuntu only.

Comment: Sorry, bad. Confused with another question. So, you running Fedora/Ubuntu VMs on OSX? Perhaps post the init.el file you are using? BTW I also noted that the font you are attempting to set is not installed on my Ubuntu Gnome system (15.04). Is there anything in the messages buffer which might give a clue? Do you see anything if you run with --debug-init? Other things to check would be .Xresources/.Xdefaults in case there is a font for emacs specified there. Note also that debian/ubuntu emacs versions have some additonal init scripts e.g. /etc/emacs